# MethodInterceptor for class extending ebean Model not working

Tags: java, playframework, guice, ebean

I have ebean entity:

```
enter code here
@Entity
public class Company extends Model {
     @Id
     public Long id;
     static void foo {
           Logger.info("in company");
     }
...
}
```

A guice Module defining the interceptor:

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {

        CacheImpl cache = new CacheImpl();
        requestInjection(cache);
        bindInterceptor(subclassesOf(Company.class), any(), cache);

    }
}
```

This does not intercept any calls made to Company (foo(), save(),get(), find()..)

When I change bindInterceptor to a class extending Play Controller, it works by intercepting the calls.

Can some one tell me if I am missing anything?

my methodInterceptor:

```
@Component
public class CacheImpl implements MethodInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation method) throws Throwable{
        Logger.info("class {}",method.getClass().getName());
        if (method.getMethod().getName() == "list") {
            Logger.info("interceptor in list");
        } else {
            Logger.info("in interceptor for  {}", method.getMethod().getName());

        }
        return method.proceed();

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you access to new instances of `Company`? Do you just `Company c = new Company()` and then expect it's intercepted? If not, please describe the way you're doing it.

Comment: One of the way its accessed is: 
Company comp =  Company.find.byId(1L);
Company.foo();

This issue is seen only when trying to intercept classes extending ebean model

I am expecting foo to be intercepted